# Greasemonkey detect private browsing mode?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need to make my Greasemonkey script behave differently if it is currently running in a Firefox Private Browsing window. Is it possible to detect this from Greasemonkey? If not, then is it possible to have it not run at all in Private Browsing mode?

EDIT: One reason I want to do that is that normally the script makes AJAX requests, which include information about the visited page and the server-side may store that information (which is OK when browsing in normal mode). If the user is in Private Browsing, though, I don't want the server-side to have the information that the user is visiting the page, so I want to have it not make these requests in that case.

Comment: No and no. More importantly, what reason do you have for wanting to do something like this?

Comment: @BrockAdams I want to make sure that in this case the script doesn't cause information to be written to persistent storage, which is the main point of Private Browsing. Seems like a reasonable requirement, no?

Comment: If that is your goal, problem solved!  Anything that your script (or the page) writes to persistent storage (not counting `GM_setValue`) will be erased when the private browsing session closes.

Comment: @BrockAdams but AFAIK, GM_setValue and/or localStorage are the ways for the script to actually save data to persistent storage and so that's what I'm using. And that's precisely what I want it not to do when running in Private Browsing mode. Also, the script makes AJAX calls, which can also result in storing data at the server-side, so, I would like it not to make those requests when in Private Browsing mode as well. Or just make the script not run at all in that case.

Comment: localStorage goes away, so you are covered there.  You aren't using GM_setValue. You should've mentioned the AJAX calls in your Q (and should edit it in now).  There is still no way for GM to detect private mode.  But ***if*** you can show a legit use-case, you can make a feature request of GM's developers for this.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sorry, you're right about localStorage, so that does indeed take care of half of the problem. Thanks. I've edited the question to include information about the AJAX calls.

Comment: Huh, 5 votes?  Might be more interest in this than I suspected.  For reference: [Make a feature request for GM at GitHub](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues)... and [How a Firefox **Add-on** can detect private mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/EN/docs/Supporting_per-window_private_browsing) (You can fork Greasemonkey for yourself while waiting for a feature request to get pulled.)

Comment: It is already implemented since greasemonkey 3.8 - https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_info

Answer (score 2):

This feature is implemented since Greasemonkey 3.8 - https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2199

You can use `GM_info.isPrivate` to check if the userscript is running in private mode window.

Comment: This doesn't work any more. The `isPrivate` property does not exist, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842220/greasemonkey-detect-private-browsing-mode

Answer (score 1):

From within a plugin in Firefox, you can detect if the browser is in Private Browsing Mode with the below code taken from [Mozilla's developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Supporting_private_browsing_mode). This is however an internal API only accessible from within plugins, not websites or third party scripts.

There is no gurantee this will help you as I am not sure if Grease Monkey expose the Components API in Firefox for use within a GM script or not. Initial searching seems to turn up nothing of the sort.

```
try {
    var pbs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/privatebrowsing;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrivateBrowsingService);

    var inPrivateBrowsingMode = pbs.privateBrowsingEnabled;

    if (!inPrivateBrowsingMode) {
    /* save private information */
    }
} catch(e){
  alert("Error!");
}
```